# Biblatex merging entries together

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm using `biblatex` with `biber` to write a CV.  In my bibliography, biblatex seems to merge all the entries into one.  I cannot understand why.  I found quite a few questions on TeX.SX where users wanted to merge entries and had to enable it explicitly using sets.  This makes it even more puzzling since I'm doing nothing like that!  A MWE is shown below.

mwe.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\newcommand*{\firstname}{Suvayu}
\newcommand*{\familyname}{Ali}
\newcommand*{\acadtitle}{}      % Academic title goes here
\newcommand*{\addressstreet}{Institute}
\newcommand*{\addresscity}{City, Country}
\newcommand*{\address}[2]{\addressstreet{#1}, \addresscity{#2}}
\newcommand*{\mobile}{+1 2 34 56 7890}
\newcommand*{\email}{email@example.com}
\usepackage[myblue]{koma-moderncvclassic}

\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=ydnt,bibstyle=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}
\defbibheading{bibliography}[Publications]{\section{#1}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Personal Information}
\cvline{Birth}{01\textsuperscript{st} Jan, 1900}

\section{Academic history}
\cventry{2012--present}{Foo}{Bar}{Baz}{}{Some comment.}
\cventry{2009--2012}{Foo}{Bar}{Baz}{}{}

\section{Research projects}
\cvline{Measuring FOO}{bla bla}
\cvline{Measuring BAR}{bla bla}
\cvline{Measuring BAZ}{bla bla}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

mwe.bib:

```
@article{Bar:5678,
  author         = {Bar, Foo and others},
  title          = {Measure {FOO}},
  year           = {2011},
}
@article{Baz:1234,
  author        = {Baz, Bar and others},
  title         = {Measure {FOO}},
  year          = {2014},
}
```

[image: Merged entries in the bibliography]

**Edit:** Based on @moewe's suggestion, I resolved my issue by undefining `\quote` like this: `\let\quote=\relax`.

Comment: Looks like an issue with `koma-moderncvclassic` to me: it only happens if that package is loaded and `\maketitle` is present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer as Joseph Wright pointed out in the comments lies in [`koma-moderncvclassic`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-moderncvclassic)'s `\maketitle`.

Just at the end we find

```
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{%
\quote}}%
    {}%
    {\centering{\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\quote}\end{minipage}}%\\[2.5em]
}%
```

That is `\maketitle` checks for a `\quote` command and if it exists prints it in a `minipage`.

Since the `\quote` command exists in your document this behaviour is triggered and the minipage is set, slightly influencing the space of the following text.

We can change `\maketitle` to do the same thing except for using `\myquote` instead of `\quote` thus avoiding the naming clash.

```
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
% name and title
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\maketitlenamewidth}%
    \firstnamestyle{%
\firstname~}\familynamestyle{%
\familyname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{%
\acadtitle}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\acadtitlestyle{%
\acadtitle}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  % optional data
\begin{minipage}[b]{\maketitledetailswidth}%
    \raggedleft\addressfont\color{addresscolor}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\addressstreet}}{}{%
      \maketitledetailsnewline%
      \addresssymbol~\addressstreet%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\addresscity}}{}{\\\addresscity}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\mobile}}{}{\maketitledetailsnewline\mobilesymbol~\mobile}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\phone}}{}{\maketitledetailsnewline\phonesymbol~\phone}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\faxnr}}{}{\maketitledetailsnewline\faxsymbol~\faxnr}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\email}}{}{\maketitledetailsnewline\emailsymbol~\emaillink{\email}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\extrainfo}}{}{\maketitledetailsnewline\extrainfo}%
  \end{minipage}%
% optional photo
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\photoname}}%
    {}%
    {\hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
     \ifthenelse{\equal{\pictureframe}{noframe}}
      {\begin{minipage}[b]{\photowidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\photowidth]{\photoname}
       \end{minipage}}
      {\color{firstnamecolor}%
       \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\photowidth]{\photoname}}}} 
% optional quote
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\myquote}}
    {}
    {\centering{\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\myquote}\end{minipage}}}%
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. However instead of redefining `\maketitle` I undefined `\quote` since I'm not using it. Although I'm getting a few `Underfull \hbox` warnings now. I don't quite understand though how this was affecting the bibliography.